# Proof butt connectors are up to code

Tags: safety

I'm about to add butt connectors to the plan for wiring my power circuit. How can I prove, with documentation, that these are safe and up to code? My location is Ontario, Canada. My application is small renewable energy (wind).

I searched all through the Canadian Electrical Code and there is not one instance where 'Butt connectors' are mentioned.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Usually the datasheet for the butt splice would have that information. Could always use J - Hooks, good enough for NASA, good enough for me!

Comment: @Stiddily What if the product is from Amazon and doesn't contain a datasheet? In that case, would you say it's probably not good enough?

Comment: Not an electrician, but generically these are "crimp connectors" (at least I assume those are the type you're referring to, not the spring types) and I would expect something related in the code, and the connectors would have to be safety-agency listed types in addition.

Comment: Where do you want to use them?  The ones I use are up listed 105C , 600v building wire, 1000v sign wire. They need to be in a box or control cabinet you can look on the container they came in or my 3M Scotchlok crimp connectors are listed , just checked my T&B sta-kon's are also listed

Comment: @Ed Beal They will be inside a (grounded) tower.

Comment: Accessible? You can't splice and pull the splice must have an access point.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying - am I splicing wires and then pulling the splice into an enclosed space - and this isn't exactly the case. The wires are spliced and then that part with the splice is put in an enclosed space. With some disassembly you can get at the splice. Are you saying that any spliced connection always has to be immediately accessible by personnel?

Comment: the problem is you are being cagey.  You are trying to get away with something, and you don't want to tell us what it is, because you think you will get shot down if you do. This is worse than  an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), because you won't even tell  us the X. **Read the XY Problem link then tell us the origin problem you are trying to solve.  We will tell you the best way to solve it.**.   Or else  I will VTC.

Comment: How do you plan to gain access to this splice point? Is there a handhole in the mast for splicing?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany -- they are treated generically by the NEC at least (need to be identified for the use, which means a listing to one of the various sub-standards within the UL486 family in practice for splices carrying load current)

Comment: In all fairness, I do see where this question was posted on electronics.se, where the rules are different, , but we need to know more about what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use connectors(and, in general, parts) approved by Canadian Standards Association(CSA) or Underwriters Labs(UL).  Parts from reputable suppliers(including better brands sold on amazon/ ebay if not counterfeit) will usually bear at least one of those two markings stamped onto the metal or in permanent marking by other means.  If you have the right qualifications it is also legal to literally prove that the product is safe (check material, calculate ampacity/ test insulation).  I don't know if it's legal for a non-professional to do this.

You could also hire someone to test them and sign off on them, but it would be much cheaper to just buy some that you are sure are decent.  You can buy legal for use plugs, switches, connectors, etc. at dollar stores, but that doesn't necessarily mean it's wise to use them.  I've pulled out dollar store receptacles with a plastic mounting strap (the tabs you run screws through to mount the receptacle) and made from not-light-resistant brittle plastics.  I doubt anyone ever got in trouble for using one, but what an unnecessary risk to take to save $0.30.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your laws are similar to the US. As long as the product is listed for the purpose you want to use them they would be legal. I have both Thomas&Betts and 3M brands and both labels show them to be UL listed 105 deg C , 600v building wire, or 1000v sign lighting luminary. This is all the proof I need. I don't use the "imported" super cheap products because they don't come with listing information if I can't prove there listed I can't use them. But since they are a splice they require a box or control panel to enclose them that is accessible.